# mainController won't get called (Angular.js)

Tags: javascript, angularjs

This is mine html file.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head ng-app="drawings">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script><!-- load jquery -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.8/angular.min.js"></script><!-- load angular -->
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lodash@4.17.5/lodash.min.js"></script>
    <script src="drawings_core.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-controller="mainController">
</body>
</html>
```

This is mine drawings_core.js file.

```
var app = angular.module('drawings',[]);
var drawing;

function mainController($scope,$http){


    $http.get('/get_drawing').success(function(data){
        console.log(data);
    }).error(function(err){cosnole.log(err);});


}
```

Content of mainController function wont't get called.
Get request is not sent.

Comment: you don't have a controller. You would need to initialise it with `app.controller("mainController", mainController)`

Comment: i have tried that already it still wont work.

Comment: var app = angular.module('drawings',[]);
var drawing;

app.controller('mainController',mainController);


function mainController($scope,$http){

    alert('test');

    $http.get('/get_drawing').success(function(data){
        console.log(data);
    }).error(function(err){cosnole.log(err);});


}

Comment: I used your code and it worked for me, check for any typos

Answer (score 0):

You need to register your controller in your application. The code could look like this, but this is not tested, you might need to make some small alterations.

I would suggest creating separate methods for your functionality. You can then call them like I did in this example.

Even better would be to create a separate service where you deal with the http stuff.

I have an example here: https://eidand.com/2015/01/22/starting-with-angular-part-3-services/

It's old, but it should be enough to get you started.

```
app.controller(mainController, ['$scope', '$http', function ($scope, $http) {

    $scope.getDrawing = function ()
    {
        $http.get('/get_drawing').success(function(data){
            console.log(data);
        }).error(function(err){console.log(err);});
    }

    $scope.getDrawing();

    }]);
    })();
```

Comment: I placed ng-controller attribute into head tag instead of body tag and it worked.